# Assigning a specific (group of) reviewers in Plone (by 'hand' or automatically)

Tags: plone

Is it possible to assign a person or a group of people as reviewers in a certain state of a workflow in Plone?

I have been looking at AutoRole en the IRolesplugin, but do not seem to find what I need?

In our case, users need a multiple review step workflow, yet the first reviewer should have control over which reviewers come afterwards...

Answer (score 1):

Workflows can trigger scripts.  Scripts can do things like grant roles to users.  You'd have to come up with an approach to letting your first specify additional users.  There are probably multiple ways to do it, but I could imagine using archetypes.schemextender or a custom content type to provide a field for choosing additional reviewers, only visible to initial reviewers.  Then use those values in the workflow script.  http://plone.org/documentation/kb/creating-workflows-in-plone/tutorial-all-pages provides a good overview of how DCWorkflow works.

Comment: Thanks Jon, as you might see , a follow-up question to the [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759083/extracting-data-from-a-string-where-the-data-structure-is-embedded-in-the-string) posed yesterday. I did it approximately like you said - I think -  by installing Dexterity and creating a new content type that includes the necessary field. Now I'm looking for some direction in 1: fetching this info from within a workflow script and 2: assign the Reviewer role to the correct group based on the fields that were added in Dexterity. Any chance of some guidance here? No pressure!

Comment: Sorry, I'm one of those people who can point you in the right direction, but I don't have the skills to provide you with the code.  :-(

Comment: Speediro, I think you meant to link this question on your comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663188/assign-reviewer-from-different-groups-at-different-stages-of-workflow-in-plone Please edit it and I'll remove mine =)